# Can I reset checkbox states in wxWidgets menu?

Tags: c++, checkbox, menu, wxwidgets

I have wxWidgets application with a couple of `wxMenu`s (Open, Edit, View, etc.).

On the View menu I have some checkboxes.

**Question**: Can I change the state of a specific checkbox withouth explicitly clicking on it ?

Comment: Did you even look in the manual? [`virtual void wxMenuItem::Check(bool check = true)`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_menu_item.html#afcfbb12e302c0528e55efcb1c6f5f7fc)

Comment: Yes but according to that documentation the function takes only 1 argument, while I need to pass the item ID and ture/false.
Anyway in my wxWidgets implementation there happens to be such an overload. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You'd run the function on the `wxMenuItem` in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void Check(int itemid, bool check)` is of `wxMenu`.
`virtual void Check( bool check = true )` is of `wxMenuItem`.
They both can check or uncheck the menu item.